# Internet drops every a few seconds on newly built PC

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I built a new PC and for some reason my internet connection drops every a few seconds all the time. It's very frustrating and I've tried different Wi-Fi adaptors, and it's not the router either. It's an AMD desktop.

I have followed every tutorial online, updated drivers, etc... Anything I am missing? I am attaching a screenshot of a recurring ping so you see what's happening.

[image]

Comment: Please Edit your question to indicate OS (I assume latest Windows 10), motherboard model, wifi adapters you've tried.  Confirm that the wifi adapters work on other devices from the same location; if you're building in a new room with bad wifi echoes, you will have problems.  Does a hardline Ethernet connection to the router work normally?

Comment: I will second what Christopher said about testing other devices. The issue could also be with your router or ISP, you just haven't noticed it until you built your new PC. See if you can try the same ping test on another PC or a mobile phone and make sure the results are good.